# How to switch off automatic kernel updates?

Tags: kernel, updates, installation

Now Nvidia with Optimus and glfrx and Bumblebee works fine here.

I want to stay with kernel 3.5.0.22 and not being automatically updated again.

How do I switch off automatic kernel updates?

Comment: You can lock packages to a certain version. The terms that will help you find something on google should be `dpkg hold package`. I'm sorry but I don't remember the syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to skip kernel update?](http://askubuntu.com/q/178324/25656).

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to do that, because you can switch back to the older kernel 3.5.0.22 in the Grub menu. [At boot you can show the Grub menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34159/show-grub-boot-menu-on-10-10-system) by holding the <kbd>shift</kbd> key. If you want you can select the [desired kernel as default kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry).

**See:**

- [Show Grub boot menu on 10.10 system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34159/show-grub-boot-menu-on-10-10-system)
- [Set “older” kernel as default grub entry [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry)

Comment: this has no harm to previous nvidia-installations ? i can always switch back in future installations ?

Comment: Yes, you can if you don't uninstall the kernel.